# Are lenses for my Canon Rebel XT compatible with the Canon 7D?

Tags: lens, canon, canon-7d, canon-350d

I am looking to purchase a 7d and currently have an XT. How do I find out if the lenses I have are compatible with the my new potential camera?

Comment: This is great, lets see how many identical answers we can come up with!

Comment: One thing the other answers don't cover is that all the lenses that work on XT will work on 7d.. :)

Answer (score 13):

Canon EOS bodies can accept two types of lenses, EF and EF-S mount.  EF work on all and EF-S only work on crop sensor bodies.  Both the XT and 7D are crop sensors so they accept either EF or EFS lenses.  If you were to purchase a full frame body such as a 5D mrk II or 1d X then you could only use EF lenses on those bodies.

Answer (score 9):

**They are all compatible.** Both have the same mount and sensor size.

On most DSLR brands other than Nikon, that is all you need to know.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does the "other than Nikon" part refer to Nikon G lenses lacking the aperture ring? Or something else?

Comment: No. Nikon lens can autofocus via an electronic or a mechanical link but not all Nikon DSLRs have the mechanical link, particularly none of the entry-level ones. So a D3100 or D5100 will not autofocus with a AF lens and requires an AF-S one. A D90, D7000, D3X or D3S can autofocus with both types of lenses. The lens will mount and be usable with MF on all these cameras.

Answer (score 4):

All Canon lenses (EF & EF-S mount) should be compatible. In fact, some of the correction features like [peripheral illumination correction](http://www.imaging-resource.com/PRODS/E7D/E7DA4.HTM) will be enabled for lenses that came out between the XT & 7D.

However, 3rd party lenses like those made by Sigma & Tamron may not work.

Quoting from [a review of the Sigma 17-50mm lens](http://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/Sigma-17-50mm-f-2.8-EX-DC-OS-HSM-Lens-Review.aspx):

> My standard disclaimer: There are some potential issues with third party lenses. Since Sigma reverse engineers (vs. licenses) manufacturer AF routines, there is always the possibility that a DSLR body might not support a (likely older) third party lens. Sometimes a lens can be made compatible by the manufacturer, sometimes not.

Comment: That is confusing when you call it peripheral illumination correction. Also known as, vignette correction!

Comment: @dpollitt Yes, I just used the Canon jargon. In a layman's terms, I'd say it corrects corner darkening that is inherent to a lens.

Answer (score 0):

**ALL** of the lens that you can currently use on your XT can be used on the Canon 7D.

Reason: they have the same mount. If it doesn't work on the XT it will not work on the 7D

Answer (score 0):

YES.

All your lenses used on the XT (350D?) can be used on the 7D.  I should know - I went from a 350D to a 7D and took all my lenses with me ;-)